# "Сам", заменяющее "один"

Tags: стилистика

В последнее время все чаще встречаю, что вместо "один" пишут "сам". Например, "он решил пойти **сам**, чтобы другие не отвлекали его разговорами". Очевидно, что здесь должно быть "один" по значению, вот если бы было "он решил пойти **сам**, а не перекладывать этот вопрос на плечи подчиненных" - тогда да.

Насколько эта ошибка "вопиющая", так сказать, насколько далеко такое употребление слов от нормы и правил? По какому правилу (если есть такие правила) нельзя заменять "один" на "сам"? Или это все же корректно?

И вообще, никто не знает, откуда это пошло? Мне кажется, что тут что-то то ли провинциальное, то ли украинское...

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, что это вполне корректно. Только здесь значение не соответствующее или не совсем соответствующее "один". Тут упор на ***самостоятельное*** действие, а не просто одиночное.

Скажем у летчиков в учебке можно сделать первый полет ***самому*** - но, естественно, с инструктором. А вот первый одиночный полет - это уже другая стадия обучения.

Сам
2.
Указывает на лицо или предмет, которые совершают действие самостоятельно, без постороннего вмешательства. И сама справлюсь! Всё сделаю сам. Уйду сам, по собственному желанию. Ругать некого: сами выбирали. Кто тарелку разбил? - Сама разбилась. Само за себя говорит что-л.
(не нуждается в объяснении, доказательстве).

(БТС)

Comment: >Тут упор на самостоятельное действие, а не просто одиночное. 

В том-то и дело, что в контексте упор делается на то, что ГГ пойдет именно один, а не сам. Обычно он ходит вместе с группой (но ходит сам и так и эдак), а тут решил - в одиночестве.

Comment: Ну тогда это ошиидка стилистическая, или еще какая-то, понимаемая только в контексте.

Answer (score 1):

А вы включите телевизор и посмотрите любое народное ток-шоу. Услышите массу контекстов типа: «Я живу сама», «Он остался сам»… Никакого сомнения: в русском языке бытует просторечное употребление «сам» в значении «один». В украинском языке такое значение этого слова, видимо, считается литературным.
По ссылке http://t-cs.ru/4656 можно найти такой текст: Учтите: в русском языке местоимение сам имеет значение «самостоятельно, без помощи»; в значении «один» не употребляется.

Comment: Здесь такие ссылки не проходят. Даже не знаю, что посоветовать.
Как-нибудь укоротить нельзя?  Вот с помощью этого сервиса хотя бы?
http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0

По сути. Вы перевернули вопрос. Спрашивали об использовании "один" вместо "сам". Не наоборот, как у вас.

Comment: Спасибо за трансформацию ссылок - как вы это делаете? научите! А перевернула ли я вопрос - доверим судить вопрошавшему..

Comment: behemothus, что "один" вместо "сам", что наоборот - для моего вопроса разницы нет

Comment: >В украинском языке такое значение этого слова, видимо, считается литературным.

Да, есть даже такое слово ***"самотА"***, т.е. *одиночество*.

.

Также подобная тенеденция, "сам" вместо "один", в отношении людей или животных, распространена на территории бывшей Югославии. 
Могу предположить, что это что-то старославянское.

Answer (score -1):

"Он решил пойти сам", то есть лично. Заменить на "один" (в таком случае) никак не получится.